# DVB device node creation Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver, dvb

Hi I am trying to create a dvb frotnend for my device on ubuntu. I have created a device driver file that creates a dummy dvb file after looking at dummy_dvb_fe.c which is present in the linux kernel. For some reason when I insmod it I am not able to see anything in my /dev folder. Generally a device node under /dev/dvb/adapter should get created. I am not sure if any other files need to be changed for front end registeration. due to the lack of documentation I am not sure about the process of creating a dvb frontend device driver and registering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I figured it out. Issue was I was looking into the Linux TV user space DVB-API documentation instead of the Media Kernel API documentation. In any case

You have to create, populate and register a dvb_adapter after which you have to create and register a dvb_dummy device.

Comment: can you share some source code?  I also want to make a dummy DVB adapter that would stream some prerecorded file on proper configuration.